# Fabric2 issue running Django management commands

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, fabric

I'm porting fabric scripts to python 3 and I'm using latest version of fabric. Locally I'm running python3 while remote is on python2. Working with regular bash commands is okay but when I want to do some Django stuff it breaks with error below:

```
from fabric.tasks import task

python = '/data/worker/ve/bin/python'
hosts = ['worker@ip-adress']

@task(hosts=hosts)
def do_that(c):
    with c.prefix('source /data/worker/ve/bin/activate'):
        with c.cd('/home/worker/ve/app'):
            # c.run(f"{python} manage.py showmigrations") this breaks
            c.run('python -V') works
            c.run('ls -la') works
            c.run('which python') works
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/data/worker/ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.apps import apps
  File "/data/worker/ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .config import AppConfig
  File "/data/worker/ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.utils._os import upath
  File "/data/worker/ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/_os.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: /data/worker/ve/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: _PyErr_ReplaceException
```

Comment: what is latest version of fabric? Can you be more specific?

Comment: You don't have to define `python = '/data/worker/ve/bin/python'` while your bash would know self which version of Python it will execute! 
so `c.run("python manage.py showmigrations")` is sufficient!

Comment: @Peshmerge running `fabric==2.5.0` Tried what you said in second comment and still getting same error

Comment: Tried the same command but with ansible and still getting that error

Comment: Also tried this fab comand on a remote running python3 and it works...